# Empty item between Owl-item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I am applying owl carousel to a list of products and an empty owl-item is generated in the middle of the elements.
This creates a very wide right-hand white space.
Ex: https://www.tia.com.ec/cybermami?lid=9ef0d86b-df76-4760-b8ab-fd5d707b29de
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb0Q3.png)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.showcase-owl-surtidos .vitrina ul').addClass('owl-carousel'),
          $('.showcase-owl-surtidos .vitrina ul').owlCarousel({
                  items: 6,
                  autoplay: true,
                  loop: false,
                  rewind: true,
                  autoPlay: true,
                  stopOnHover: !0,
                  pagination: !1,
                  itemsDesktop: [1299, 5],
                  itemsDesktopSmall: [1099, 4],
                  itemsMobile: [575, 2],
                  navigation: !0,
                  navigationText: [
                    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="43.751" height="65.502" viewBox="0 0 43.751 65.502"><defs>  <filter id="Left" x="0" y="0" width="43.751" height="65.502" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">    <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>    <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>    <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>  </filter></defs><g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#Left)">  <path id="Left-2" data-name="Left" d="M61.551,1107.8,39.8,1129.555l21.751,21.751" transform="translate(-28.8 -1099.8)" fill="none" stroke="#aaa" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4"/></g></svg>',
                    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="43" height="64" viewBox="0 0 43 64">  <defs>    <filter id="Right" x="0" y="0" width="43" height="64" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>    </filter>  </defs>  <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#Right)">    <path id="Right-2" data-name="Right" d="M21,0,0,21,21,42" transform="translate(32 50) rotate(180)" fill="none" stroke="#aaa" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="4"/>  </g></svg>',
                  ],
                });
        });
```